# How to disable android hiding an activity on keycode_button_... events?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a rooted tabled with an USB port in host mode to read the value of an xbox-controller-joystick (with onJoystickMotion).

Now, I also want to track the buttons `keycode_button_a`, `keycode_button_b`, `keycode_button_x`, `keycode_button_y` and `keycode_button_select`. The tracking is working, but pressing these buttons will hide the activity.

Is there any way to disable android hiding an activity on this `keycode_button`_... events?

Comment: What does your key handling method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    InputDeviceState state = getInputDeviceState(event);
    if (state != null) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (state.onKeyDown(event)) {
                    //Do my thing
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (state.onKeyUp(event)) {
                    //Do my thing
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Yeah :D